# tree control doesn't show the image associated

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to create a tree control that displays the folder structure of all the drives in the System for which i am using CTreeCtrl. I want to add the Folder image to the treectrl and used the following code to test but i am surprised that the image is  not shown up.

```
CImageList m_ImageList;     
CBitmap m_Bitmap1;  
m_ImageList.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR, 0, 1);       
m_Bitmap1.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);  
m_ImageList.Add(&m_Bitmap1, (COLORREF)0xFFFFFF);        
m_cTreeCtrl.SetImageList(&m_ImageList, TVSIL_NORMAL);   
HTREEITEM hTree = m_cTreeCtrl.InsertItem(L"C Drive", 0, 0, TVI_ROOT); 
HTREEITEM hCompany = m_cTreeCtrl.InsertItem(L"Program Files", 0, 0, hTree);     
m_cTreeCtrl.SetItemImage(hTree , 1, 1);
```

My Bitmap id is IDB_BITMAP1 is bitmap for the folder.
I see a blank space beside the text instead of the image.

Please correct me. Thanks

Comment: Indices into an image list are zero-based. You are passing `1` as the index to `SetItemImage`, even though there is only a single image in the image list, at index `0`.

Comment: Yes, agree with @llnspectable. Also, make sure m_ImageList is memberof the class and not local variable.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same problem, while working with images on GDI sdk(win32). For solution of this you may:-

1. Check size of bmp images, as it will not support bigger than frame.
2. I fixed with direct APIS. like "LoadImage(...)/SetImage(...)" on
   SDK..

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. An answer should not require feedback from the OP.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/resizable-controls-mfc-pankaj-kumar Pankaj